# Android Studio, cannot find symbol method from already added dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, smooch

I have a weird problem when compiling my project in Android studio. I have two dependencies that kind of affect each other. When I have,
    `compile 'com.github.dbachelder:CreditCardEntry:1.4.7'`
the project compiles fine and works great. However, if I add,
    `compile 'io.smooch:ui:latest.release'`
and compile project again, the methods from firstly added dependency

> (com.github.dbachelder:CreditCardEntry:1.4.7) cannot be found.

I attempted:

clean,
 rebuild,
 ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build,
Sync with Gradle Files,
Closing Android Studio and re-opening,
Invalidate caches & restart,
 I even tried to import the CreditCardEntry repo to project manually.

If, I remove the dependency
 
    `compile 'io.smooch:ui:latest.release'`
Again project compiles fine and find the methods of CreditCardEntry dependency.

**The error:**

> Error:(160, 16) error: cannot find symbol method clearForm()
>
> Error:(161, 16) error: cannot find symbol method
>   setOnCardValidCallback(CardValidCallback)
>
> Error:(163, 16) error:
>   cannot find symbol method focusCreditCard()

Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`io.smooch.ui` actually contains `com.devmarvel.creditcardentry` as an embedded dependency, and it's using the same namespace. My first hunch would be that you have a namespace conflict.

This feels like a bug on the Smooch SDK side, the embedded dependency probably should be re-namespaced to avoid conflicts like this. (Disclaimer: I work on Smooch, I'll file a bug on our end)

An immediate workaround that might work is to remove your `com.github.dbachelder:CreditCardEntry:1.4.7` package for now and see if you can resolve `com.devmarvel.creditcardentry.CreditCardEntry` and `com.devmarvel.creditcardentry.CreditCardForm` from the Smooch UI package instead.

Comment: Well, I was expecting something like this. Thanks for help, I can still import them after removing it, as you suggested. But the methods that are in the original class again are unresolved, except some.